# I can not save any configurations from the admin panel

Tags: magento2, admin, error

I can not save any **configuration** from the **Admin panel**, after saving the **settings** and **clean the cache**.
There are no written records and no error message is seen.

[Video of error](https://youtu.be/0E6TDEvcFbE)

Comment: in which version,Magento or Magento2?

Comment: @vicabitu, Provide more detail to understand the exact problem, if possible share some reference.

Comment: Share a video from problem https://youtu.be/0E6TDEvcFbE

Comment: I use Magento 2.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to disable unused extensions, clear cache